# What if I'm not satisfied with the answers to the question I posted a bounty on?

Tags: discussion, bounty

In [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2075/bounded-input-bijections-of-infinite-sequences), I offered a bounty, but there are only two answers which really qualify as non-answers.  I asked in a comment for the OP to post an answer so I could award him the bounty for asking a cool question, but he hasn't done so.

Would it be kosher for me to post a non-answer myself, award myself the bounty, and then put a bounty on another question?  Would the software even permit that?  Other suggestions?

Comment: I do not think that you can award the bounty to yourself.

Answer (score 5):

If all answers are really non-answers, I guess the best solution is to let the bounty expire (and let the software do whatever it does in these situations).

A bounty is always risky. You are not guaranteed to get a good answer even if you offer a bounty. And the system is really built so that you can't get your bounty back.

Comment: Thanks.  FYI there is now a candidate answer for this question.

Comment: ... which was just deleted by the answerer.  Sigh.

Comment: IIRC when the bounty expires the software gives half the bounty amount to the answer with the most up-votes.

Comment: I think this happens only if the answer has some positive votes (probably +3, but I don't remember exactly how many).

Comment: From FAQ: If you do not award your bounty within 7 days, the highest voted answer created **after the bounty started** with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to award the full bounty to the most upvoted answer, since it was going to receive half the rep anyway.  If someone posts a solution to that problem in the future, I'll start another bounty so I can award rep to the solver.